# Graph API for email in c# is throwing 0DataError when I order by receivedDateTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have the following c# code:

```
    var result = _userClient
        .Users[_email]
        .Messages
        .GetAsync(conf =>
        {
            conf.QueryParameters.Filter = QueryFilter;
            conf.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "receivedDateTime" };
            //conf.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "receivedDateTime asc" };
            conf.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "attachments" };
            conf.QueryParameters.Top = 1;
        })
        .Result;
```

When I uncomment the Orderby line, this code throws a 0DataError exception.

I tried different capitalization, desc and could not find help for this in the documentation.

Comment: QueryFilter is just a string: "startswith(subject, 'something') and from/emailAddress/address eq 'some@email' and hasAttachments eq true";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$filter` and `$orderby` in the same query must follow [some rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#using-filter-and-orderby-in-the-same-query) to be working, otherwise Graph API returns the error `InefficientFilter: The restriction or sort order is too complex for this operation`.

Based on the rules:

1. Properties that appear in `$orderby` must also appear in `$filter`.
2. Properties that appear in `$orderby` are in the same order as in `$filter`.
3. Properties that are present in `$orderby` appear in `$filter` before any properties that aren't.

You need to add `receivedDateTime` at the beginning of the filter:

```
string QueryFilter = "receivedDateTime ge 2022-06-26T07:00:00Z and startswith(subject, 'something') and from/emailAddress/address eq 'some@email' and hasAttachments eq true"
var result = _userClient
    .Users[_email]
    .Messages
    .GetAsync(conf =>
    {
        conf.QueryParameters.Filter = QueryFilter;
        conf.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "receivedDateTime" };
        conf.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "receivedDateTime asc" };
        conf.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "attachments" };
        conf.QueryParameters.Top = 1;
    })
    .Result;
```